# PiCamera not detected

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi2, picamera

I started working with a fresh Raspi. Enabled the camera module from `raspi-config`, rebooted my RPi.
When I then ran this simple code:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
camera=PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
```

I get this long error saying Camera is not enabled. Try running 'sudo raspi-config' which I already have.

Additionally I tried running `vcgencmd get_camera` it says `supported=1 detected=0`

**I have inserted my camera in correct orientation** Double ensured it. But I'm still stuck. Appreciate any help.

Comment: your question would probably get a better answer on [Raspberry Pi Stackexchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Try taking a picture with `raspistill` to see if the hardware is found.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some issue when connect the camera with raspberry pi.

1. Maybe your charger is not well enough to give the proper power for raspberry pi. or
2. Maybe the cable which connect the camera and raspberry pi is broken. or
3. Maybe the slot for connecting the camera is broken.